# Sorting observable collection in Radgridview

Tags: c#, silverlight, telerik, radgrid, radgridview

I am using telerik Radgridview in silverlight application. In that i have bind the itemsource with observable collection. Whenever the collection is changed, the radgridview.ItemSource is bound to observable collection. Everythings works fine but whenever item is added to collection, it is just append in the grid. I want to sort the collection after adding. Is there any simple way out for that?

Answer (score 0):

Depends a on your implementation details, but I think you should be able to do it most cases with the OrderBy in LINQ and the CollectionChanged event. You just have to resubscribe to the event. Here's the code that worked for me in quick test:

```
public class BindingViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public BindingViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        Items.CollectionChanged += Items_CollectionChanged;
    }

    public void Add(int value)
    {
        Items.Add(value);
    }

    private void Items_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<int>(Items.OrderBy(x => x));
        Items.CollectionChanged += Items_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<int> _items;
    public ObservableCollection<int> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }
}
```